# Erro ao mudar orientação da tela usando fragments

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-fragment

Ao girar a orientação de tela recebo esse erro:

**Erro android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment**

***Pergunta:*** O que poderia estar causando o erro?

**Contextualização:**

- O aplicativo abre normalmente porém ao tentar rotacionar a tela acontece o erro, após receber o erro colocoquei o código da activity que contém o hostfragment dentro de um try-catch, e ao girar a tela o app não fechou, porém não inflou o layout. Já tentei mudar muitas coisas e várias soluções de vários sites e de amigos porém nenhuma conseguiu de fato resolver o problema.
- Após vários testes percebi que apenas o fragment login está fazendo
  isso, se eu for para qualquer outro o erro não acontece.

O erro aponta exatamente para essa linha:
**setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);**

Essa é a activity onde está o fragment host:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}

}
```

Fragment host está no arquivo xml da activity:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/host_fragment_login"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/login_navigation"
    />
```

Log do erro:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: athamuso.easyservico.easyparceiro, PID: 3017
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{athamuso.easyservico.easyparceiro/athamuso.easyservico.easyparceiro.LoginActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3131)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4939)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1986)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.downEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:263)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.backwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:314)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:334)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:145)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.setCurrentState(LifecycleRegistry.java:118)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.updateState(NavBackStackEntry.java:150)
        at androidx.navigation.NavBackStackEntry.setMaxLifecycle(NavBackStackEntry.java:130)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.popBackStackInternal(NavController.java:325)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.dispatchOnDestinationChanged(NavController.java:426)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.onGraphCreated(NavController.java:636)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:586)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:551)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.setGraph(NavController.java:533)
        at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2684)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1175)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.onCreateView(FragmentLayoutInflaterFactory.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:135)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:356)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:335)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:780)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:995)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:859)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at athamuso.easyservico.easyparceiro.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:19)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7148)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7139)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1293)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3270)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:5030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4939)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityRelaunchItem.execute(ActivityRelaunchItem.java:69)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1986)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:220)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6939)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:870)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 3017 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Vi que deram um -1 em minha pergunta, há algo de errado ? estou lendo sobre como fazer as perguntas no fórum porém não achei erros, agradeceria bastante caso alguém pode-se me ajudar a melhorar minha pergunta.
Já procurei bastante por ai e não consegui nada que ajudasse.

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o problema é na IDE Android Studio, ao renomear o **ID** do primeiro fragment que está no graph(Área responsável pelo navegação) está renomeando automaticamente o id do próprio navgation, então **o navigation e o fragment estavam ficando com ID idênticos**:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_login"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_login">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_cadastro"
        android:name="Cadastro"
        android:label="Cadastro"
        tools:layout="@layout/cadastro_fragment" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_login"
        android:name="teste"
        android:label="fragment_teste"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_teste" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_teste2_to_nav_cadastro"
            app:destination="@id/nav_cadastro" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**Solução:** Não usar o editor visual da IDE, opte por mudar manualmente pelo menos até ajustar os ID,faça diretamente pelo código se não ele vai mudar ambos os ID ao mesmo tempo e vai persistir o bug.